# tlbexp.exe outputs different tlb information on 2012 versus 2010

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have a C#  assembly that uses "$(FrameworkSDKDir)\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\tlbexp.exe" "$(OutDir)My.dll" /out:"$(TLBDir)My.tlb"  so that I can call it from native components

I am looking at
[.tlh generated on 2 machines is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911461/tlh-generated-on-2-machines-is-different) and it appears to be a similar problem, but my difference is in visual2010 the tlh is generated using one case, and in 2012, it is generated using a different case.

Even more interesting this just happened a day ago. I have a build from the 18th that worked just fine, and the code has not changed in either solutions for many days.

Any thoughts before i continue down the /Names option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot easily tell you what to do to solve this problem, just highlight why this is happening.  It doesn't have much to do with Tlbexp.exe, it is generic behavior implemented in the type library support built into Windows.

It has a tricky problem to solve, it cannot make any assumptions about the *kind* of language that was used to generate the types.  The troublemakers are languages that are case-insensitive, Visual Basic being the prime example.  Also the original language for which type libraries were invented.  The issue is that it may emit names that can have different casing in different declarations but identify the same type.  If the type library would use the same casing then it could only ever be consumed by a language-insensitive compiler.

So it does something about it, the algorithm it uses can at best be described as *crude* however.  It looks at *any* name, regardless of what part of a declaration it is used, then forces the casing of any subsequent same name it encounters to the same casing.  The usual big surprises are caused by names of function arguments.  They can change the name of a function if it happens to match.  So an "item" argument, pretty common, can spoil the name of an "Item" property.  Or the other way around.

The wild-card here is *order*, I suppose that could be half an explanation.

Best way to address the problem is to change the name so there is no longer a collision.  You have no trouble finding them, it is the one that changed casing.  You may have to iterate a few times to find them all.  Given that it is usually the name of an argument that causes this, feel free to change the argument name.  Just put an underscore after it for example, it doesn't break binary compatibility nor the client code.